# Intermittently getting HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I understand this question has been asked A LOT. But my case is a bit different.
I am getting the error `Found shared references to a collection: ClassB.classA` intermittently and whenever I get this, a simple service restart fixes the issue most of the times.

No setter calls are ever made to ClassB.classA from the service methods and the only time I believe a setter is called is by Hibernate itself while retrieving the entities from the database.

The entities are defined as -

ClassA

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "tableA")
@IdClass(ClassAId.class)
public class ClassA {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "refId")
  private int refId;

  @Column(name = "someprop")
  private String someProp;
}
```

Class B

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "tableB")
@IdClass(ClassBId.class)
public class ClassB {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private int id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Eager, targetEntity = TaxHours.class) 
  @JoinColumn(name = "refId", referencedColumn = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Where(clause = "someprop NOT IN (...)")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  @BatchSize(size = 100)
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  private List<ClassA> classAList;
}
```

DAO implementation

```java
public interface ClassBRepository extends JpaRepository<ClassB, ClassBId> {
  @Query("SELECT b "
      + "FROM ClassB b "
      + "WHERE b.id in ?1")
  List<ClassB> findAllById(List<Integer> classBIdList>
}
```

Service implementation

```java
public void updateClassB(List<Integer> idList) {
  List<ClassB> classBList = classBRepository.findAllById(idList);

  /**
  Make some updates to the properties of the above list items,
  without ever touching classA list in the entities.
  **/

  classBRepository.saveAll(classBList);
}
```

One thing I have noticed is that I get this error only when the classAList property of ClassB comes out to be empty.

spring-boot version: 2.5.12
spring-data-jpa version: 2.5.10
hibernate-envers version: 5.6.7.Final
hibernate-jpamodelgen version: 5.6.7.Final
hibernate-jpamodelgen version (annotationProcessor): 5.6.7.Final